# Android Dialogue Fragment not moving up when keyboard is visible

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

I have implemented a custom dialogue fragment which contains a custom view pager and an edittext.View pager contains a grid. To move the view upwards when keyboard is visible I have placed the view inside a scrollview. When app is running view pager is not displaying. How can I make this custom fragment scrollable when keypad is visible. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to the corresponding activity tag in your application manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried everything, however the problem was not in the implementation of the dialog, or how the keyboard was invoked. I was using a theme to make the status bar translucent and that caused the wrong behavior, by changing to another theme the dialog goes up without problems when invoking the keyboard. I hope my answer is helpful

I was using this style

```
 <style name="TranslucentTheme" parent="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
  </style>
```